# Terminal path is not an actual place

Tags: python, macos, terminal, path

When I opened terminal today, all commands (ls,touch, python ...) don't work. I look up online and find out it is because the path in terminal gets replaced. So I open the .bash_profile and find this below. I comment out the last line and terminal gets normal again.

So I have this question, **where does the last line come from? And what are those special characters?**

(The day before, I installed pygames. Is it possible cause?)

```
 #added by Anaconda3 4.3.1 installer
export PATH="/Users/test/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
export PATH=‚Äô/usr/local/bin:Äô
```

Comment: Could you please add to your question (not as a comment) the output of `uname -a` as well as the output of `env`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like there was either an issue during the install or a file encoding error, but as a fix instead of commenting out the last line you should change it to:

`export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"`

as that seems like what Anaconda was trying to do there.

Comment: To complete the answer: `’` (U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK) is encoded to UTF-8 as `\xe2\x80\x99`. Those bytes are interpreted as `‚Äô` if the file is decoded using MacRoman encoding. Either way, it's wrong to use these characters instead of ASCII `"` or `'` in shell scripts.

Comment: Hi, after I fix it, the ternimal says this. Should I just keep one path?`/usr/local/bin:/Users/test/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin': not a valid identifier

Comment: @VivianChen: Make sure you copied the line correctly; from that error, I suspect you have an extra `$` before the first occurrence of `PATH`.